# Storing images in SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image

I want to store images of my employees with their profile details in SQL in a SQL Server database, but I have following reservations:

Should I compress images or not and if yes, please can the community provide me sample code or direct me to a guide that can assist me with this.

How should I retrieve images efficiently? I am afraid of asp.net application performance issues. I think with thousands of employee records, the system may halt or slow down.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest storing the path of the images on your sql table, and actually store the image in a secure folder. This has worked for me perfectly.

Comment: but when i need to take back up of my database ? then and secobdly viruses may corrupt my image folder

Comment: just zip the image folder and store it in the same media as your db backup. You could also store the images on the same db server drive, just outside of SQL database. If you have the images on the same machine as your db, I doubt if a virus can get to it (given normal security processes in place)

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server is well equipped to handle large amounts of binary data, but as always, the devil is in the details and the design:

To avoid any performance issues that can happen with reporting or access from other applications due the Sql Server's paging process (all db engine use pages as a discrete unit of data manipulation) I would place the image data in a separate table that is linked 1-to1 to your employee table. Doing so will keep the binary data from being moved around with employee queries unnecessarily when accessed from other parts of your system. Your image display logic will of course have to join on the two tables to match up employee and image records.

Comment: This is bad advice. SQL Server already separates BLOBs into their own allocation unit for storage (separate B-Tree), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189051.aspx.

Comment: Whether it's bad advice might depend on the version of sql server used. That link is to a sql  2008 article. Also, this type of organization isn't necessatily bad. There may be many reasons why a dba might want split a table in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, ten thousand records is nothing ... as long as you have the right indexes in place SQL Server will handle that with ease.

However, consider just using the file system to store things like images. The SQL Server record could just contain a pointer (ie. path) to the file and the asp.net application could just use that to read the file from disk and stream it to the browser.

Comment: but when i need to take back up of my database ? then and secobdly viruses may corrupt my image folder

Comment: @barq: True, the images are not a part of the database backup. Sometimes that's a good thing, sometimes it's a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Most image formats (such as JPEG, or PNG) already employ some compression algorithm, so unless your source is a RAW image or an uncompressed bitmap, additional compression won't help much. What might help is limiting the size of the image, say a maximum of 400 x 400 pixels. I don't know what the intended purpose is so I don't know if this will work well for you. Obviously, if you are storing the data directly from a digital camera, the images will be very large and you might want to scale them down first, to something more reasonable.

Comment: how can i limit my size image at user end

Comment: @barq: you'd have to write code for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL server 2008 or above then you can use the filestream feature that is like the best of both worlds. It stores the image in the filesystem but has it under transactional control and is also included in your backups when they are taken.

If you are not on 2008 or above then I would say to keep the images in the DB, see this old Microsoft white paper for my reasons why.

http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs.DB/0701168